# JS Alert not showing when using Sharepoint list value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

I am using Sharepoint 2007 and writing a web part. In the "RenderContents" method I am writing the html code for displaying page. there is a requirement to display alert message to user when they click a link.
I have written following code-

```
string alertmessage = Utility.GetLocalizedText("NavigatingToNewPageTxt", "RCCResources", "Common");

writer.Write("<a href='" + clubMemberReportsLink + "' target='new' onClick='alert('" + alertmessage + "');' > ");
```

Note- My requirement is to get the alert message from Sharepoint list as we use SP list for translations.
when I refreshed the site link was displayed but alert message did not appear.when I checked what was rendered in browser I got following code in browser.

```
<a href="../../securememberservices/Pages/ContribReport.aspx" target="new" onclick="alert(" this="" is');'=""> ClubLeaderDownloadreportsText</a>
```

I tried using following code as well

```
writer.Write("<a href='" + clubMemberReportsLink + "' target='new' onClick=alert('" + alertmessage + "'); > ");
```

(I removed the single quote from onclick method.)Still the browser does not display alert message. 
this behavior is observed in both browsers. I know I am missing something very simple here...
can you pleas point out any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to escape the quotation marks for so that the onclick string is not terminated. Like:

```
onclick='alert(\"" + alertmessage + "\");'
```

Hope that helps!